# Contexto de filtro DAX - Powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax

Tenho uma planilha simples para controle de abastecimentos de combustíveis

3 colunas:
Data do abastecimento\ Placa do Carro \ KM no odômetro no ato do abastecimento.

Quero montar uma medida para sabe quanto foi rodado em KM

Para isso precisava pegar a Maior KM - a menor KM para cada PLACA(diferente carro) e somar tudo.

Problema é que não consigo quebrar por carro dentro da medida, a não ser que eu explicite filtrando carro a carro. Porém podem ser cadastrados outros carros, e não será possível atualizar a medida.

Se eu utilizar essa medida aqui:

KM Rodado = CALCULATE(SUM(ftAbastecimentos[Km]),LASTDATE(ftAbastecimentos[Data de abastecimento]))-CALCULATE(SUM(ftAbastecimentos[Km]),FIRSTDATE(ftAbastecimentos[Data de abastecimento]))

Eu uso a coluna data para pegar o KM na menor e maior data que aparecem, subtrair e somar.

Se eu coloco essa medida em uma tabela junto com a coluna placa, aparece o resultado para cada placa da forma certa. Precisava achar uma forma de somar aqueles valores.

Comment: Se a resposta foi útil, lembre-se de marcá-la como correta.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi bem, entendo que você quer saber um valor total, independentemente de haver filtro aplicado para um veículo. Nesse caso, é necessário, dentro da fórmula DAX, eliminar o referido filtro com a função `ALL ()`.

Por exemplo:

```
KM rodado = 
VAR KM_INICIALES = CALCULATE (SUM (ftSupplements [Km]), LASTDATE (ftSupplements [Fecha de suministro]), ALL(ftSupplements)) 
VAR KM_FINALES = CALCULATE (SUM (ftSupplements [Km]), FIRSTDATE (ftSupplements [Fecha de suministro]), ALL(ftSupplements))

RETURN
KM_FINALES  - KM_INICIALES
```